# Handsontable Cannot Type in JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog, handsontable

I got a lot of trouble with javascript today, and those brought me out a lot of headache.
But the most problem for me now is, cannot type in the handsontable cell when it popped out in jquery ui dialog.
I read some article, that by default, jquery ui dialog prevent any outside function, to make sure every actions that comes up on the dialog, are its child.
I've read [this](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/1480) article, which ask us to override the jqueryui dialog so that can allow "copy paste" (this is from their problem, but it's important for me to know, how to override jquery ui dialog plugin).
And I still work around with my problem, (because I still can't make any progress with previous link), and I came up with this another article : [cke_editor in jqueryui dialog](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087#comment:30)
and also I found this fiddle : `[cke_editor in jquery ui doalog][3]`

And this is what I've done.

First I try to override, as the first link said, like written in this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /**
         * overriding jqueryui dialog
         */
        (function($) {
            $.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
                _allowInteraction: function(event) {
                    console.log("override");
                    if(this._super(event)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return $(event.target).hasClass('copyPaste');
                },
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

And it bring e nothing, so I try the second approach like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.widget( "ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
        /*! jQuery UI - v1.10.2 - 2013-12-12
        *  http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087#comment:27 - bugfix
        *  http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4727#comment:23 - bugfix
        *  allowInteraction fix to accommodate windowed editors
        */
        _allowInteraction: function( event ) {
            if ( this._super( event ) ) {
                return true;
            }

            // address interaction issues with general iframes with the dialog
            if ( event.target.ownerDocument != this.document[ 0 ] ) {
                return true;
            }

            // address interaction issues with dialog window
            if ( $( event.target ).closest( ".handsontable" ).length ) {
                return true;
            }

            // address interaction issues with iframe based drop downs in IE
            if ( $( event.target ).closest( ".handsontable" ).length ) {
                return true;
            }
        },
        /*! jQuery UI - v1.10.2 - 2013-10-28
        *  http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10269 - bugfix
        *  moveToTop fix to accommodate windowed editors
        */
        _moveToTop: function ( event, silent ) {
            if ( !event || !this.options.modal ) {
                this._super( event, silent );
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The basic idea at 2nd approach is telling you that, you need to open interaction with outside plugin, (in this case cke_editor, but I need to tweak it out to handsontable plugin interaction)

And if I put it all together, this is what we've got :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>HOME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/jqueryui/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/jqueryui/jquery-ui.theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/jqueryui-bootstrap/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/form.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/well.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/modifier-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap-dialog.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/formstone/dist/css/scrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/scrollbar/jquery.custom-scrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascripts/rest/handsontable/handsontable.full.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jqueryui-bootstrap/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/dialogextend/build/jquery.dialogextend.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/formstone/src/js/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/formstone/src/js/touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/rest/handsontable/handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/rest/table.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/rest/request.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/rest/response.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.widget( "ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
            /*! jQuery UI - v1.10.2 - 2013-12-12
            *  http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087#comment:27 - bugfix
            *  http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4727#comment:23 - bugfix
            *  allowInteraction fix to accommodate windowed editors
            */
            _allowInteraction: function( event ) {
                if ( this._super( event ) ) {
                    return true;
                }

                // address interaction issues with general iframes with the dialog
                if ( event.target.ownerDocument != this.document[ 0 ] ) {
                    return true;
                }

                // address interaction issues with dialog window
                if ( $( event.target ).closest( ".handsontable" ).length ) {
                    return true;
                }

                // address interaction issues with iframe based drop downs in IE
                if ( $( event.target ).closest( ".handsontable" ).length ) {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            /*! jQuery UI - v1.10.2 - 2013-10-28
            *  http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10269 - bugfix
            *  moveToTop fix to accommodate windowed editors
            */
            _moveToTop: function ( event, silent ) {
                if ( !event || !this.options.modal ) {
                    this._super( event, silent );
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /**
             * overriding jqueryui dialog
             */
            (function($) {
                $.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
                    _allowInteraction: function(event) {
                        console.log("override");
                        if(this._super(event)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return $(event.target).hasClass('copyPaste');
                    },
                });
            })(jQuery);

            $body = $("body");

            $(document).on({
                ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading"); },
                ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
            });

            var main = new Main();
            main.initialize();

            /**
            * sample code for populating window content and function
            * this.winEventObj is Main object property
            */
            var winEvent = function(){
                // $("#save").click(function(){ alert("save clicked"); });
                $(".ui-dialog").on("click", "#save", function(){
                    alert("save clicked");
                });
            }

            main.winEventObj = new Object();
            main.winEventObj.content = "<div>This is "+1+" content <button id='save'>Save</button></div>";
            main.winEventObj.callEvent = function(btnType, btnId){
                winEvent();
            }

            main.winCollection.push(main.winEventObj);

            $(document).load("well_mgmt/items/log.html", function(content){
                main.winEventObj = new Object();
                main.winEventObj.content = content;
                main.winEventObj.callEvent = function(btnType, btnId){
                    var container = document.getElementById('log_table');
                    var data = function () {
                        return Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(100, 12);
                    };

                    var memberData = [
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"],
                        ["Nama #1","Pria","Jakarta","24/02/2015","Jl Alpina 4 No 14 Dago Asri Bandung"]
                    ];

                    var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                        data: memberData,
                        height: 396,
                        colHeaders: [
                            "Nama Lengkap",
                            "Jenis Kelamin",
                            "Tempat Lahir", 
                            "Tanggal Lahir", 
                            "Alamat Asal" 
                        ],
                        rowHeaders: true,
                        rowHeight: function (row) {
                            return 50;
                        },
                        stretchH: 'all',
                        columnSorting: true,
                        contextMenu: true,
                        columns: [
                            {type: 'text'},
                            {type: 'dropdown', source:['pria', 'wanita']},
                            {type: 'text'},
                            {type: 'date', dateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY', correctFormat: true},
                            {type: 'text'}
                        ]
                    });
                }

                main.winCollection.push(main.winEventObj);
            });

            /**
            * end of sample code for populating window content and function
            */

            main.initTree();
        });
    </script>



</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And that 2nd approach, requires the plugin name (which is, I don't know what the handsontable plugin name is).
If you take a look any closer, you'll find this at 2nd approach :

```
// address interaction issues with dialog window
if ( $( event.target ).closest( ".handsontable" ).length ) {
    return true;
}

// address interaction issues with iframe based drop downs in IE
if ( $( event.target ).closest( ".handsontable" ).length ) {
    return true;
}
```

The closest(".handsontable"), is just my guess, I just think that, the proper name for allowing outside action interacion with handsontable plugin, is using ".handsontable".

So, what the proper method, to allowing handsontable events working inside jqueryui dialog (so that it can typed inside handsontable cell)

Very beg your help, please...:(